# Show The Desired/Specific Frequency

Tags: java, android, audio, fft

I've made an android apps about visualize spectrum frequency from recording sound. I'm using package from www.netlib.org/fftpack/jfftpack.tgz to perform FFT. We know that Each line of spectrum handle frequency from this formula : "((frequency_sample/2)/samples)". Its easy to see the first, second, and third spectrum that occurs. But, above fifth spectrum its hard to determine which spectrum it is.

I want to know the specific frequency (for example freq 200Hz) is occur or not and show it as toast or something like that. Is there any good source library I could refer to do this?
Thanks :)

```
package com.example.agita.stethoscopeandroid;

/**
 * Created by Agita on 5/21/2015.
 */
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import ca.uol.aig.fftpack.RealDoubleFFT;


public class RekamActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button startRecordingButton, stopRecordingButton;
    TextView statusText;
    File recordingFile;

    boolean isRecording = false;


    int frequency = 8000;
    int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
    int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    private RealDoubleFFT transformer;
    int blockSize = 256;

    RecordAudio recordTask;
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rekam);
        statusText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.StatusTextView);
        startRecordingButton = (Button) this .findViewById(R.id.StartRecordingButton);
        stopRecordingButton = (Button) this .findViewById(R.id.StopRecordingButton);
        startRecordingButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopRecordingButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopRecordingButton.setEnabled(false);

        transformer = new RealDoubleFFT(blockSize);
        imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        String recordedAudioFile = getRecoredAudioFile();
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/Datarekaman/");
        path.mkdirs();
        try {
            recordingFile = File.createTempFile("recording"+recordedAudioFile, ".wav", path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't create file on SD card", e);
        }
    }

    private String getRecoredAudioFile() {
        String returnAudio;
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
        returnAudio = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date.getTime());
        return returnAudio;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == startRecordingButton) {
            record();
        } else if (v == stopRecordingButton) {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }


    public void record() {
        startRecordingButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopRecordingButton.setEnabled(true);
        recordTask = new RecordAudio();
        recordTask.execute();
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        isRecording = false;
    }


    private class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, double[], Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            isRecording = true;
            try {
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                                recordingFile)));
                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
                AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                        MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency,
                        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);
                short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
                double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];


                audioRecord.startRecording();

                while (isRecording) {
                    int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0,
                            blockSize);
                    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                        dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
                        toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i]/32768.0;
                    }
                    transformer.ft(toTransform);
                    publishProgress(toTransform);

                }
                audioRecord.stop();
                dos.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
            }
            return null;
        }

        /*protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            statusText.setText(progress[0].toString());
        }*/

        protected void onProgressUpdate (double[]... toTransform) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (int i = 0; i < toTransform[0].length; i++) {
                int x;
                x = i;
                int downy = (int) (100 - (toTransform[0][i] * 10));
                int upy = 100;
                //canvas.drawRect(x * 3, downy, x * 3 + 4, upy, paint);
                canvas.drawLine(x, downy, x, upy, paint);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            startRecordingButton.setEnabled(true);
            stopRecordingButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you be clearer about the problem? I don't understand it from the description you have given.

Comment: @marko for exampe I want to know sound with freq 200 Hz occurs or not. Its hard to see from the spectrum since the line spectrum is really small and no scale. Thats my problem, i dont know if that freq is occurs or not just by looking on spectrum

Comment: if want to know freq 200 Hz by knowing the magnitude, is it right if I do like this? `if (i == 13){
                    magnitude += Math.sqrt(Math.abs(toTransform[0][i]));
                }`